# HOW To ASSIGN THE OUT PUT OF THIS EXECUTIOn TO VARIABLE

Tags: shell, unix

I am newbie in shell script , may be stupid query to experts, I am using following code to remove leading and trailing spaces from value, how do I assign output of echo variable to StringVar variable again or to other Variable. I am using ksh shell.

```
StringVar= ' abc  '    
 echo StringVar | awk '{$1=$1};1'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x=$(command)
```

where `x` is the variable to which you want to assign the output of the command.

In your case, do not give space before or after the assignment operator `=`

```
StringVar=' abc  '
x=$(echo "$StringVar" | awk '{$1=$1};1')
```